# USB to PS/2 converter

Tags: usb, keyboards, mice

I have a USB wired keyboard and wireless Mouse with a USB receiver. Almost every USB port I have is used, so I wanted to relieve the ports of some burden by transfering my keyboard and mouse to PS/2 ports. I have ASUS PRIME A320M-K motherboard. I recently purchased cheap USB [female] to PS/2 [male] adapters, only to find out that they're of no use. In the logs, I have seen this:

```
i8042: PNP: No PS/2 controller found
```

So, I reckon there is no circuit inside those adapters that will actually convert USB signals to PS/2 signals. By the way, I'm not sure what they are good for.

I'm looking for recommendations regarding hardware that will solve the problem by making me able to utilize my PS/2 ports properly, thus freeing up the USB ports.

I've searched online, and the only thing I could find is rather expensive for such a simple device (~$150).

Comment: Frame challenge: USB hub or PCIe card.
Theoretically an adapter should work, but it may be drawing too mich power. There also seem to be USB HIDs that simply won't work over an PS/2 connector.

Comment: Had such a thing many years ago, it just worked...  But yes, go for a USB hub.  Even better, a screen with a usb hub built in, this will help to arrange the cables much better.

Comment: The keyboards and mice that support those female USB -> male PS/2 adapters use a chipset that can sense whether it's connected to a USB or PS/2 port. The adapters are passive (just pin to pin) so the keyboard or mouse is outputting an actual PS/2 signal over the USB wires when it senses the adapter. Converting from USB to PS/2 doesn't really make sense unless it's specifically for a mouse or keyboard, so the "adapter" is almost always built into the keyboard or mouse instead of being standalone.

Comment: Agree with the existing comments. Unless you have a particular objection to getting a USB hub, I think that's probably an appropriate solution. @towe, if you'd like to post an answer, feel free; if not, I can do it.

Comment: Something like a [Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) should be able to do this (with the proper physical adaptation of the connector, etc.), though it may also be overkill. But I don't know if it is feasible. Aren't there some standard solutions based on Raspberry Pi already? But the search engine results are clouded out by either the other way around (from PS/2 to USB) or the passive adapters that just do the mechanical adaption (for keyboards that work both as PS/2 and USB).

Answer (score 0):

Some USB devices appear to not support communication over PS/2 adapters very well.

Frame challenge:

Use a decent, perhaps actively powered, [USB hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DQFGH80), or install a [PCIe USB card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z34BJYH) to give you more freedom with your USB ports.